# Retrieving Values from selected rows in C# Datagridview with joined tables in SQL

Tags: c#, datagridview, ssms, windows-forms-designer

This query works in SQL with the specified ID, however, when i try to get the value of the selected row from the datagrid view, it gives me an error saying the table does not have a primary key. (It does)

**Where the error occurs**

```
drAssignmentDue = dsStudentManagementSystem.Tables["Assignment"].Rows.Find(dgvAssignmentsDue.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

**Result**
*System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException: 'Table doesn't have a primary key.'*

The aim of this code is to auto-fill components on the windows form from the selected row in the datagrid view. This worked when it was just the columns from 'Assignment' (before i added the joins. After the joins where used, the issue crashes and gives me : *This table does not have a primary key* error.

**The SQL query within C#**

```
sqlAssignmentDue = @"SELECT a.AssignmentID, a.AssignmentName AS Name, a.ReleaseDate AS Released, a.DueDate AS Due, a.Submitted, a.Score,
asD.ModuleCode,
aStu.StudentID

 FROM Assignment a

 JOIN AssignmentDetails asD ON a.AssignmentID = asd.AssignmentID
 LEFT JOIN AssignmentStudents aStu ON a.AssignmentID = aStu.AssignmentID

 WHERE aStu.StudentID LIKE '" + txtGradeStudentID.Text + "' AND a.Submitted = 'false'";

 daAssignmentDue = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlAssignmentDue, connStr);
 daAssignmentDue.FillSchema(dsStudentManagementSystem, SchemaType.Source, "Assignment");
 daAssignmentDue.Fill(dsStudentManagementSystem, "Assignment");
 dgvAssignmentsDue.DataSource = dsStudentManagementSystem.Tables["Assignment"];
 dgvAssignmentsDue.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
 dgvAssignmentsDue.Refresh();
```

**Other Source Code**
**Assignment Table in SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE Assignment 
(

AssignmentID        INT     NOT NULL,
AssignmentName      VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
ReleaseDate DATE            NOT NULL,
DueDate             DATE    NOT NULL,
Submitted           BIT     NOT NULL,
SubmissionDate      DATE        NULL,
Notes           VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
Score           INT     NULL

CONSTRAINT pkAssignmentID PRIMARY KEY (AssignmentID)
)
```

I am trying to retrive the selected value of a row in the Data grid view,
The DGV displays a selected students assignments that are due.
The student is selected in another section.
The data grid view is populated from the selected student. The assignments due datagridview is a query using table joins to get the specific students modules and details.

This works **without the joins** How do i set a primary key when the table already has one?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataTable` doesn't have a primary key, exactly as the error message is telling you. The fact that your database tables have primary keys is irrelevant. You `DataTable` contains data from both of them, based on a join, so it won't magically inherit a primary key from a database table. If there's a logical candidate column(s) then you have to set the `PrimaryKey` property yourself. If there isn't then you can't do anything that requires a primary key.

The thing is, what you're doing is pointless anyway. What you should be doing is binding all your controls to the same data. That way, when the user selects a row in the grid, all the other controls will be populated automatically. Any changes you make in those controls will be automatically pushed to the data source and then reflected in the grid.

You should add a `BindingSource` to your form, bind the `DataTable` to that and then bind that to your grid and the rest of the controls, e.g.

```cs
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable;
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource;
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myBindingSource, "ColumnNameHere");
```

When the user selects a row in the grid, the `TextBox` will display the field from the "ColumnNameHere" column. No additional code required.

Comment: I have code that automatically fills the components from the selected row in the dgv using DataRow.  'txtAssignmentID.Text = drAssignmentDue["AssignmentID"].ToString();'
How would i set the primary key property myself? I cant seem to find anything on it. I have never using Bindingsource for anything so its rather new to me.

Comment: @Sean, *"I have code that automatically fills the components"*. And that is wrong. You should be using data-binding, unless you have a specific reason not to. Do you have such a reason?

Comment: *"I cant seem to find anything on it"*. Then you haven't looked, because every type and every member in the framework has documentation and you should ALWAYS read that documentation for yourself before asking any questions here or anywhere else. You could even just use Intellisense: type a dot after your `DataTable` variable and you'll get a list of members and that list will provide the type and a description. Once the member name is selected, you can click it and press F1 to go directly to the relevant documentation.